# How to get bottom-most child elements of XML document that have a value (i.e. no other child elements)?

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse an XML document that extracts the lowest-level child elements. Here is an XML document example (conceptually):

```
<outerelement>
    <insideElement1/>
    <insideElement2>
        <insideElement3>
            <child1>testval1</child1>
            <child2>testval2</child2>
            <child3>testval3</child3>
            <child4/>
            <child5>
                 <child51>testval51</child51>
            </child5>
            <child6>textval6</child6>
        </insideElement3>
    </insideElement2>
    <insideElement4>
</outerelement>
```

What I would like to retrieve out of this is {"child1", "child2", "child3", "child51", "child6"} i.e. the child elements that strictly contain values but do not have children themselves.

My attempt is this:

```
private static ArrayList<String> array;

// ...

private static ArrayList<String> findChildren(Node documentElement) {

    if (!documentElement.hasChildNodes()) {
        array.add(documentElement.getNodeName());
    }
    NodeList nl = documentElement.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            doIt(currentNode);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

But for various inputs that I give the method, it either gives incorrect results or not all the correct results.

Comment: I could use regex if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See a regex solution.](http://regex101.com/r/iK7bB9/1) You can capture at the node itself:

```
/<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/gm
```

> `<(.*?)>` matches anything between brackets as capture group 1 lazily and the brackets themselves.
>
> `.*?` matches anything after the bracket as few times as possible. This allows jumping to the next part of the regex quicker:
>
> `<\/\1>` Asserts that there is a literal **<,/** and the captured element from capturing group 1, then a literal **>**.

Here have code, it reuses the `Pattern` for efficiency:

```
// Class
private static final Pattern FIELD_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>.*?<\\/\\1>");

// Method
{
    Matcher matcher=FIELD_PATTERN.matcher(document_string);
    while(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

[Here's a live code demo.](http://jdoodle.com/a/7Y)

Sample STDOUT:

> child1
>   child2
>   child3
>   child51
>   child6

Comment: That's horrible. Never use regular expressions to parse XML. It is not a regular language. The solution is incorrect: it will match things that are not leaf elements, for example it will match processing instructions, or things that look like elements but are actually in comments or CDATA. In fact, it will fail completely on CDATA. It even fails on elements that contain attributes, or on elements that have whitespace in their start or end tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath expression `//*[not(*)]`. This selects all descendant elements that do not have an element child.